# Adding multiple numbers in if and case statements

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing my first game app for the iphone, and I'm still a bit nooby in objective-c.

The game is coming along fine but i'm stuck on a little problem...

I want to make it so that for every 20 kills, you get +1 life, I know how to do that but with poorly written code such as this...:

```
    switch (kills) {

        case 20:

            lives++;

            livescount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", lives];

            break;

        case 40:

            lives++;

            livescount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", lives];

            break;

        case 60:

            lives++;

            livescount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", lives];

            break;
        case 80:

            lives++;

            livescount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", lives];

            break;
        case 100:

            lives++;

            livescount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", lives];

            break;

        case 120:

            lives++;

            livescount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", lives];

            break;
        case 140:

            lives++;

            livescount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", lives];

            break;
        case 160:

            lives++;

            livescount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", lives];

            break;

        case 180:

            lives++;

            livescount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", lives];

            break;

        case 200:

            lives++;

            livescount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", lives];
```

and so on.... I don't want to keep writing this till infinity lol

---

I know for a fact that this is an improper way to write the code. Can anyone give me a proper code for every 20 kills = +1 life. I would probably spot on and understand how the code works too.

Answer (score 4):

Use the modulo operator (%) that return the remaider of division by 20 ; also check that the number of kills is different from zero.

```
if (kills != 0 && kills % 20 == 0) {
    lives++;
    livescount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", lives];
}
```

Comment: This gives an extra life if there are no kills.

Comment: Can someone further explain what it means? I want to make sure I know what it is so that I can understand Objective-C a bit more.

Comment: The % operator is the modulo operator - it returns the remainder of the division. For example, the quotient of the integer division of 23 by 10 is 2 : `23 / 10 = 2` ; the remainder of the integer division of 23 by 10 is 3 : `23 % 10 = 3`. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)), paragraph "Division of integers"

Comment: In your case, as you need to run the code whenever kills = 20, 40, 60, 80... it is equivalent to check that the reminder of the division by 20 is zero.

Answer (score 0):

You should use mod, so:

```
if (kills && kills % 20 == 0) {
  lives++;
}
```

Mod (`%`) returns the remainder of the division: so in this case if kills is exactly divisible by 20 it will return zero.

Good luck!

Comment: This gives an extra life if there are no kills.

Comment: what about this
if(kills != 0 && kills%20 == 0 )

Comment: This would probably work but i don't know i'm not on my mac at the moment... However I don't want my kills to be 0 again, it will mess up the score, I guess i'll make another invisible int such as kills2 but it would be so much work lol

Comment: @user2748685 This does not modify the value of `kills`.

Comment: @rmaddy hmmm then why does it have 20 == "0"?

Comment: @user2748685 You need to learn the basics of C and Objective-C. The expression `kills % 20 == 0` means: Does the value of "kills modulo 20" equal zero.

Comment: @rmaddy That's what I'm trying to do, I have basic knowledge but not all, I have a loophole idea on how I can make this work... I can make an invisible int similiar to "kills" and call it kills2 and make it so that if there are 20 kills2 it goes back to 0 and adds a +1 life, and starts over again... It may be still improper but it's way better than my previous code and uses less bytes lol

Comment: @user2748685 There is no need for an extra variable. This answer (with the extra check for no kills) or the other similar answer is all you need. Every 20 kills will result in an extra life.

Comment: @rmaddy I'll try them out in 3 days when I go back home, if it fails (which i doubt it would), i'll just use my idea. thank you all!

Comment: My understanding is that this code will only ever run when there is a kill, in which case kills should never equal `0`. For the sake of clarify I have added in the test though.

Comment: @user2748685 - It'll work ;) Think of it this way: if kills is 20, then `20 % 20 == 0` and you get an extra life. If kills is 21, then `21 % 20 == 1` so the test fails. If kills is 22, `22 % 20 == 2` so the test fails. If kills is 40, then `40 % 20 == 0` and you get an extra life. If kills is 67, then `67 % 20 == 7` and the test fails. It's a little like saying 'Divide by 20 and then give me the remainder'. If the number is exactly divisible by 20 then the result of the `% 20` operation will equal zero and the test will pass.